# preventDefault's strange behavior

Tags: javascript, events

I am really confused about how `preventDefault` function works. In the following example I expect when I drag `elem2`, the drag event get cancelled and it does. But why the `elem3` drag event is cancelled too when I drag `elem3`?

Lets clarify more: When you drag a draggable element , the `dragstart` event is fired on that element and all its ancestors. Here when you start dragging `elem3`, because event capture is `false`, the event [bubbles up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling) from `elem3` to `elem1` (a `true` event capture just makes the order of firing reversed). So when you start dragging `elem3` the event fires first on `elem3`, then `elem2` and finally `elem1`. When there is no `preventDefault` you can drag all three elements. When I add `preventDefault` to `elem2`, you cannot drag it anymore. But now I cannot drag `elem3` either. Why? There is no `preventDefault` in `elem3` event handler!

```js
const elem1 = document.getElementById("elem1");
elem1.addEventListener("dragstart", elem1EventHandler, false);

const elem2 = document.getElementById("elem2");
elem2.addEventListener("dragstart", elem2EventHandler, false);

const elem3 = document.getElementById("elem3");
elem3.addEventListener("dragstart", elem3EventHandler, false);

function elem1EventHandler(event) {
  console.log("target: " + event.target.id);
  console.log("currentTarget: " + event.currentTarget.id);
}

function elem2EventHandler(event) {
  console.log("target: " + event.target.id);
  console.log("currentTarget: " + event.currentTarget.id);
  event.preventDefault();
}

function elem3EventHandler(event) {
  console.log("target: " + event.target.id);
  console.log("currentTarget: " + event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

```css
#elem1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#elem2 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

#elem3 {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1" draggable="true">
  <div id="elem2" draggable="true">
    <div id="elem3" draggable="true">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Event bubbling. Put console logs in your event handlers and see which handlers are invoked when you drag elements.

Comment: I am aware of that but still I don't understand.

Comment: When I drag `elem3` both `elem3` and `elem1` event handlers are invoked. So I don't see any reason `elem1` not to be draggable.

Comment: @Dante That's because your divs are nested - each one depends on the previous one. `elem2` would also be called, but its event handler is suppressed by `preventDefault()`. Read my answer for more information.

Also, in your example, `elem1` is draggable. Only `elem2` and anything further are not.

Comment: @Chix Sorry but being nested is not a reasonable answer. Also pay attention I did not use `stopPropagation`.

Comment: @Dante Why not? The standard use case for a `div` is to host other elements, a `div` by itself doesn't represent anything without CSS. If you had a `div` of buttons and you want them to not submit a form, you'd call `preventDefault()` on the `div` and not on each button individually, which is why I think it's reasonable behaviour.

Comment: @Chix Now I see your point. So it is a feature of `drag` event. It drags the whole container. If it is so, please edit your answer with the new information in your new comment.

Comment: @Chix I take back my words. The most nested element is a container as its own too. If you remove `preventDefault` you can drag all three elements and their descendants individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 stages with DOM events

1. An event propagates in DOM from the source element to the document (unless it doesn't bubble like `focus` and you don't use capture). So methods like `stopPropagation()` don't work to stop the default action.
2. The browser could take a default action associated after the propagation is done (either stopped or not). That's where the browser checks whether the default action was cancelled by `preventDefault()` in the propagation stage.

By listening on a parent element you actually get both the parent's events and its children's events due event propagation/bubbling. To prevent the default action only for the parent check `event.target`. Now you can drag the orange child:

```js
const elem2 = document.getElementById("elem2");
elem2.addEventListener("dragstart", event => event.target === elem2 && event.preventDefault());
```

```css
#elem1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#elem2 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

#elem3 {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1" draggable="true">
  <div id="elem2" draggable="true">
    <div id="elem3" draggable="true">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that if you use `function` as an event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element you listen with the handler, so it could be written also like this:

```js
document.getElementById("elem2").addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  event.target === this && event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#elem1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#elem2 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

#elem3 {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1" draggable="true">
  <div id="elem2" draggable="true">
    <div id="elem3" draggable="true">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "By listening on a parent element you actually get both the parent's events and its children's events", it's wrong.  It all depends on the target element and then all its ancestors not children.

Comment: @Dante not wrong, it's different pov, it's about all potential events, not about a current one which could have a different target

Comment: your "potential events" = my "all its ancestors".

Answer (score -1):

Applying `preventDefault()` to a `div` container causes the default behaviour to stop in the container itself and everything inside it, including other containers. In your example, `elem3` is nested in  `elem2`.

In this example, you can drag the gray container, since it's not nested in elem2, but can't the dark green one, because it is.

```js
const elem1 = document.getElementById("elem1");
elem1.addEventListener("dragstart", elem1EventHandler, false);

const elem2 = document.getElementById("elem2");
elem2.addEventListener("dragstart", elem2EventHandler, false);

const elem3 = document.getElementById("elem3");
elem3.addEventListener("dragstart", elem3EventHandler, false);

function elem1EventHandler(event) {

}

function elem2EventHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function elem3EventHandler(event) {
}
```

```css
#elem1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#elem2 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

#elem3 {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral
}

#elem4 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green
}

#elem0 {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray
}
```

```html
<div id="elem0" draggable="true">
  <div id="elem1" draggable="true">
    <div id="elem2" draggable="true">
      <div id="elem3" draggable="true">
        <div id="elem4" draggable="true">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for downvote. I did not get your point in the first place. What you said in the first paragraph is correct.